# Saving JPG image from Documents to Photo Album - Sample Code

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, photo-gallery

I have generated JPG image, saved to Documents folder, that not comes with bundle.
Please help with the building class for saving it to Gallery.

Finnaly with help of [kviksilver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278993/kviksilver)

To make complete solution:

//  tools.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tools : NSObject {

}

@end
```

//  tools.m

```
#import "tools.m"

@implementation tools

-(IBAction)saveImage{

    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file7.jpg"];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,@selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
@end
```

In the end have to call it from CPP wrapper:

```
void onCPPSaveImgToCamRoll ( )
{
    return saveImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try getting imagePath like this:

```
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.jpg"];
```

then setting image:

```
 UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,@selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: will be called when finished saving or failing

just create two methods in your class:

```
-(void)saveImage{ 

NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSString *imagePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.jpg"]; 

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]; 

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,@selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);


} 
- (void)savedPhotoImage:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInf{ 

// possible error handling

}
```

and you should be ok –

Comment: dont forget to include savedPhotoImage:didfinish... method so that app doesnt crash.. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is in the first page of the UIImage Class Reference.

```
void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   UIImage  *image,
   id       completionTarget,
   SEL      completionSelector,
   void     *contextInfo
);
```

Comment: one of the blessed few that is actually completely straight forward :D